# Problem when compiling GCC in Ubuntu

Tags: compiling, gcc, install-from-source

I have run into the well known problem when installing GCC:

```
configure:3605: error: in /usr/local/gcc-4.8.1/i686-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure:3608: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
```

Although this is well discussed error. My situation is different. I have installed `GMP 5.1.2`,`mpc 1.0.1`, and `mpfr 3.1.2`. AND I have set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the directory where all the libs are located.

I can finish the configure part successfully, but still run into the problem mentioned above. I'm trying to install `GCC 4.8.1`.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: are you trying to _install_ gcc, or _compile_ it?